# React native-echarts line chart issue is minorSplitLine not working in xAxis and yAxis

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**[native-echarts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-echarts) minorSpitLine is not working in react native app, but is working properly same code on the web page(Browser).
Any help with this issue?**

**package.json**

```
 "react-native": "^0.64.3",
 "expo": "~43.0.0",
 "echarts": "^5.2.2",
```

**Line chart code:**

```
     xAxis: {
        type: 'time',
        minorSplitLine: {
          show: true,
          lineStyle:{
            color: '#D3D3D3',
          }
        },
        splitLine:{
          show: true,
          lineStyle:{
            color: 'gray',
          }
        },
      },
      yAxis: {
        type: 'value',
        minorSplitLine: {
          show: true,
          lineStyle:{
            color: '#D3D3D3',
          }
        },
        splitLine:{
          show: true,
          lineStyle:{
            color: 'gray',
          }
        },
      },
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Echarts](https://github.com/apache/echarts) library made to work only in browsers.

> Apache ECharts is a powerful, interactive charting and data visualization library for **browser**

Try to find an alternative in [reactnative.directory](https://reactnative.directory/?search=charts)